# Multiple Macro: copy sheet -> edit copied sheet -> save copied sheed -> delete copied sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am not a VBA pro, so I am struggeling with a macro that can do severeal steps:

1. to copy the "Sheet 1" within the same file ("Database") and name it "XL"
2. in the new Sheet ("XL") copy range A1-A5 and E3-E5 and paste just values in the same cells (there are some formulas in the cells that i don´t want to use in the new "XL" sheet any more)
3. save the new Sheet ("XL") to the desktop (name of the new File:  "Workbook A") and delete the "XL" sheet from the initial workbook ("Database"). But let the both files to stay opened

well thats it :-). I would be super happy if anyone can help me !

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Are you struggling with a macro where you have actually typed something resembling code or are you struggling with typing any code at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a worksheet to no destination, a new workbook is created with a single worksheet being a copy of the original.

```
Option Explicit

Sub newXLws()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Copy

    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Worksheets(1)
            .Name = "XL"
            .Range("A1:A5") = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A5").Value
            .Range("E3:E5") = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E3:E5").Value
        End With
        .SaveAs Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\Workbook A", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your macro ist perfect!

Comment: Can you please edit it a bit? I need 2 more things: 1) save the new sheet into a specific folder (folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Projektierung_KW" & Range("E1").Value & "_" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "\" ....... If Dir(folder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir folder    2) your macro paste the values in A1:A5 and E3:E5 in the original file. I want the original file to be without changes, so just the new file/sheet has to be changed/pased values.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. I don't see any reason why you should have any difficulty with those changes 2. No, you are misreading the code. Go back and check the actual results.

Comment: 1) you are right...it was my mistake!
2) where and how exactly should i edit the macro? I edited DIM as: ,Dim ws As Variant, folder As String' .... and where exactly schould I put the following step:
folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Projektierung_KW" & Range("E1").Value & "_" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "\"  ..... If Dir(folder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir folder

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402807/vba-excel-macro-save-as-part-of-cell-with-date/47403223#47403223) instructive. If you have trouble with that, please post a new question with updated code.